# ListView with a progress bar populated by Model property

Tags: listview, mvvm, xamarin.forms, progress-bar, inotifypropertychanged

Dears,

I would like to create a listview with some information of model, using INotifyPropertyChanged to populate and update my information in realtime. But when I try to use binding in my Progress function, it didn't work.

My view is:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Forms"
             x:Class="H2XA.View.PatientView"
             Title="Pacientes">

        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <Label x:Name="Paciente1" Text="Paciente"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                    />  
              <ListView x:Name="Patients" 
                          ItemSelected="OnSelection"
                          IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                    <MenuItem Text="Renomear" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                         Clicked="Renomear_Clicked" />
                                </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                <StackLayout Padding="5,0,5,0">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Font="16"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Medidas}" Font="14" />
                                    <ProgressBar ProgressColor="{Binding Bar_Color}" 
                                     Progress="{Binding CurrentProgress}" 
                                     PropertyChanged="ProgressBar_PropertyChanged"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

and

```
 public partial class PatientView : ContentPage
    {
        public PatientView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = App.PVM;
            Patients.ItemsSource = App.PVM.AllPatient;
        }
        private async void OnSelection(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            await DisplayAlert("Selecionado", e.SelectedItem.ToString(), "Ok");
            string a = e.SelectedItem.ToString().Substring(0, 12);

        }

        private void Renomear_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //replace name
            var item = (MenuItem)sender;
            (item.CommandParameter as Patient).Name = "new name";

        }


        private void ProgressBar_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        //This is the way that i found.
        var item = (sender as ProgressBar) ;

        if(item.Progress==0)
        item.ProgressTo(1, 15000, Easing.Linear);

        if (item.Progress == 1)
        item.ProgressColor = Color.Green;

        }
    }
```

This is the way that i find to populate my list of ProgressBars into Objects. But it doesnt like a good way to implements the soluction, cause I can't control the time of my ProgressBar and Easing "Linear" its not really linear to great numbers.

The first parameter of ProgressTo is Progress, that I want to show on the time that i set together it in secound parameter.

I would like to implements into my Model as a Parameter of my Object.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using H2XA.ViewModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace H2XA.Model
{
    public class Patient:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime examdate;
        public int cronometro;
        public decimal barCronometro;
        public Color Bar_Color;
        private string name;
        private string medidas;

        public Patient()
        {
            cronometro = 0;

            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),  () =>
            {
                if (cronometro < 6)
                {
                    Bar_Color = Color.Blue;
                    cronometro++;
                }
                else
                {

                    if (cronometro == 60)
                    {
                        Bar_Color = Color.Red;
                    }
                }


                CurrentProgress = (cronometro / 60);


                return true;
            });

        }

        private decimal _currentProgress;
        public decimal CurrentProgress
        {
            get { return _currentProgress; }
            private set
            {
                _currentProgress = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();//Esse comando faz a tela ser atualizada quando algo é inserido.

            }
        }
        public string Medidas
        {
            get { return medidas; }
            set
            {
                medidas = value;
               OnPropertyChanged();//Esse comando faz a tela ser atualizada quando algo é inserido.

            }
        }

    }
}
```

But when I do it in this way, there isn't animation and do not update the time in figure, only when finisehd the time the condiction work and my bar appears filled. I don't know if my binding works well and for me i did some that make sense.

I'm checking the code and notice that my ProgressBar_PropertyChanged is called everytime and it's not good to my eficiency in apps too. Could anyone help me to improve my code and organize my function to organize better my MVVM project.

Thanks in advance

Guilherme Marques

Comment: Have a try with `OnPropertyChanged();` Changing to this  `OnPropertyChanged("CurrentProgress");` in **Patient** Model Class.

Comment: It didn't work @JuniorJiang-MSFT.

Comment: Note: If you remove the "ProgressBar_PropertyChanged" and wait the time to complete the bar. When it completed ( "Progress=1" ), there isn't animation during the way but appears in final a filled bar .

Could it be a problem with "ProgressTo" ? How can I solve it ?

Comment: There is no problem with `ProgressTo`.Because when model changed , do not invoking ProgressTo,so just in final a filled bar.Equal to effect of progress = 1 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When **ProgressBar** not in **ListView**.
   You should **[Overriding the Binding Mode](https://www.jimbobbennett.io/animating-xamarin-forms-progress-bars/)**,the default binding mode on the target property is `OneWay`.When your model data changed ,the progress of progressbar has been setted there.It does not trigger this method of `ProgressTo`.

Here you should use the binding mode is `TwoWay`,it will show correctly.

Sample code as follow:

**Xaml:**

```
 <ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar" 
                     Progress="{Binding CurrentProgress,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                     PropertyChanged="ProgressBar_PropertyChanged"/>
```

**ContentPage:** When Model Data changed ,it will work.

```
private void ProgressBar_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //This is the way that i found.
            var item = (sender as ProgressBar);

            //if (item.Progress == 0)
                item.ProgressTo(1, 15000, Easing.Linear);

            //if (item.Progress == 1)
                //item.ProgressColor = Color.Green;

        }
```

And you can remove `ProgressBar_PropertyChanged` method .When data changed,do  like as follow:

```
   dataModel.CurrentProgress = 0.8;
   ...
   progressBar.ProgressTo(dataModel.CurrentProgress, 3000, Easing.Linear);
```

2. When **ProgressBar** binded in **ListView** with **MVVM**,it can not happen `Animation`.Here is a [article](https://www.jimbobbennett.io/animating-xamarin-forms-progress-bars/) for reference.

**Solution:**

Here is a method by using `Timer` to scheduled tasks to change data of progress.

```
Timer timer; // create a timer
DataModel dataModel; // data model
private double ApiProgressData = 0; // Simulate data from Api
```

Init Timer and its event handler:

```
 timer = new Timer();
 timer.Interval = 100;
 timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;

  private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {   
        if (ApiProgressData > dataModel.CurrentProgress)
        {
            dataModel.CurrentProgress = dataModel.CurrentProgress + 0.01;
            if ((ApiProgressData - dataModel.CurrentProgress) < 0.00001)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    timer.Stop();
                });

            }
        }
        else if (ApiProgressData < dataModel.CurrentProgress)
        {
            dataModel.CurrentProgress = dataModel.CurrentProgress - 0.01;
            if (( dataModel.CurrentProgress - ApiProgressData ) < 0.00001)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    timer.Stop();
                });

            }
        }else{
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    timer.Stop();
                });
        }
    }
```

After Api data changed, using Timer to change data of Model:

```
 ApiProgressData = 0.8; //  Simulate data is 0.8 to test
 timer.Start();
```

Or you can have a try with Third party library ,as mentioned in the article above.

Comment: You can't use x: Name="progressbar" because it's is a list of progress bars and u can't use the same name in all of it. Didn't work.

Comment: I put the "if(item.Progress==0)" because this method is calling all the time. When you set this method without "if"s the linear looks like a logaritmic curve and have never finished cause every call you set a new time to progress.

Comment: I saw the link that you send me in " Overriding the Binding Mode" but over there i read that default is oneway and not twoway. Bwt, I tried this code tht u send me but didn't work probably because the things that I said before. Thank you a lot to try to help in this problem.

Comment: Just giving a sample code for reference, detail code need by your logic.The default binding mode not always the one,it will change by different control.Twoway is default in ListView,however ProgressBar not it.

Comment: Sorry for previous answer.If  want to use progressBar in Listview, do not need set binding mode of OneWayToSource.However, MVVM can not get ProgressBar ,so this animation can not happen.If want animation,suggest that use timer to let data changed like animation.If not, you can use Third part library for ProgressBar.https://www.jimbobbennett.io/animating-xamarin-forms-progress-bars/ .I will update answer with Timer solution.

Comment: The problem was the mode in binding. I change my binding to twoway and work :)

Could you put the first part of code that u send me in the first time setted to mode="twoway" i want to give you the anwers for help ... so put it organized and i set the question as solved :)

Comment: Okey.Glad that you solve it.This is the code of setting binding mode.`Progress="{Binding CurrentProgress,Mode=TwoWay}"`